# Meta Business API and Cloud API creating issues when trying to send product from a catalogue to whatsapp as an interactive product card

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-business-sdk, facebook-business-manager

I am trying to create a workflow where based on user queries we send some products from the Facebook business catalog to WhatsApp as a single product and list product card as mentioned in the below link:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/commerce-guides/share-products-with-customers

I have created a permanent access token using the system user and I am able to access the catalog and also the products inside the catalog with the access token.

Also using the same token I am able to send normal text and images on whatsapp.
Now the issue is when I am trying to send specifically a product as an interactive card, I am getting the below mentioned issue.

```json
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#131009) Parameter value is not valid",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 131009,
    "error_data": {
      "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
      "details": "Invalid catalog_id."
    },
    "error_subcode": 2494010,
    "fbtrace_id": "AgVHaK1LySusku-_NFpkCNR"
  }
}
```

But the catalog exists and I am also able to access products inside this catalog.

### Fetching all the catalogs

[image: Fetching catalogs]

### Fetching products inside a catalog

[image]

### Sending Messages as an interactive card for the catalog

[image]

Comment: Documentation says, _"Unique identifier of the Facebook catalog linked to your WhatsApp Business Account. This ID can be retrieved via Commerce Manager."_ - have you checked there? Maybe that gives you a different ID, I dunno.

Comment: Yes I tried, Its same ID which appears here